# how to mysql join for two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables:

table-1: advance

```
id advance_id vamount
1 101 10000
2 101 20000
3 101 10000
```

table-2: purchase

```
id advance_id item amount
1 101 Shirt 500
2 101 Pant 700
3 101 Pen 500
4 101 Shoe 1000
```

What I want to do, sum of vamount against each advance_id from table-1 and purchase information from table-2 against same advance_id. While trying by the following query:

```
SELECT sum(a.vamount) as vamount, p.item, p.amount FROM advance as a INNER JOIN purchase as p ON a.advance_id=p.advance_id WHERE p.advance_id=101
```

I want to fetch the result in this way:

```
Total Advance Amount: 40000
item amount balance
shirt 500 39500
pant 700 38800
pen 500 38300
shoe 1000 37300
```

but it is returning one one row in result set.

How to do it in right way?

Comment: Post your desired output

Comment: a bit unclear. Can you please post the expected result?

Comment: I have posted the expected result. Please look at now.

Comment: The expected result posted is not a table expression, hence there is no query able to produce something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.item, sum(a.vamount) as vamount, p.amount FROM advance as a INNER JOIN purchase as p ON a.advance_id=p.advance_id WHERE p.advance_id=101
group by p.item
```

Comment: @Abdullah How does this query produce `balance` field of the second table expression of posted result set?

Answer (score 0):

You query should like this

```
SELECT sum(a.vamount) as vamount
    , p.item
    , p.amount 
FROM advance as a 
INNER JOIN purchase as p ON a.advance_id = p.advance_id
WHERE p.advance_id=101
GROUP BY p.item
    , p.amount
```

Use `GROUP BY` clause  and optional you can remove `WHERE` clause for group all items